# How to plot a function with changing parameter?

Tags: plotting

I am solving a problem of finding fixed points, checking their stability
and plotting the bifurcation diagram.
so I want to plot this function for a whole range of a:
dx/dt=2(a^2 - x^2)-(a^2 + x^2)^2
to get the fixed points.
I tried this code, but nothing appeared.
 `Plot[2*(a^2 - x^2) - ((a^2 + x^2))^2, {x, -10, 10}]`
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Parameter `a` should be defined before plotting!

Comment: But I don't want to plot the function at a specific value of a

Comment: Use, for instance `Table`, to define the function to be plotted for several values of `a`.  You also could use `Plot3D` to plot the function for a continuous range of `a`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want `a` to be an arbitrary parameter you can try to use [Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[2*(a^2 - x^2) - ((a^2 + x^2))^2, {x, -10, 10}], {a, -10, 5}]
```

> [image: rec]

Comment: Thanks, that will help me. I have another question How can I plot [2*(a^2 - x^2)] and              [- ((a^2 + x^2))^2] as 2 functions in the same graph?

Comment: @Doaamahmoud in the usual sense of using `{}` inside the `Plot` command. For the comment it would be something like `Manipulate[
 Plot[{2*(a^2 - x^2), -((a^2 + x^2))^2}, {x, -10, 10}], {a, -10, 5}]`

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Doaamahmoud you are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, x_] = 2*(a^2 - x^2) - ((a^2 + x^2))^2;
```

`f` is an even function in both `a` and `x`

```
{f[-a, x] == f[a, x], f[a, -x] == f[a, x]}

(* {True, True} *)

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[f[a, x], {a, 0, 10, 2}],
 {x, -10, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, HoldForm@f[a, x]}),
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0, 10, 2],
   LegendLabel -> a],
 PlotRange -> {-20000, 0}]
```

[image]

On a `Log` scale

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[f[a, x], {a, 0, 10, 2}],
 {x, -10, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  (Style[#, 14] & /@ {x, HoldForm@f[a, x]}),
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0, 10, 2],
   LegendLabel -> a],
 PlotRange -> {-20000, 0},
 ScalingFunctions -> "SignedLog"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this code and your generous help.